# How do I run the AAA command through the command interface?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

for example, I will take the command to export a document to htiml using the [asciidoc extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=asciidoctor.asciidoctor-vscode).

What command can be written in the terminal to run it through vscode?

Or maybe you can make a task for the command, which I usually run through the command pallet (`Ctrl+Shift+P`)?

[image]

p.s. I'm not interested in how you can simulate a command. I want to execute it with vscode tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This task (in tasks.json) will run that command:

```
  "tasks": [

    {
      "label": "asciiDoc to html",                 // whatever name you wish
           // find the command name from the extension or from Keyboard Shortcuts
      "command": "${command:asciidoc.saveHTML}",   
      "type": "shell",
      "problemMatcher": []
    }
  }
```

Run the task with the asciiDoc file you want converted as the current editor.  That task can be assigned to a shortcut if you wish (in keybindings.json):

```
  {
    "key": "alt+r",                               // whatever keybinding you want
    "command": "workbench.action.tasks.runTask",
    "args": "asciiDoc to html"                    // same name here as in your task
  }
```